# What 2D engine can I use to port my flash game to iOS and Android?

Tags: 2d, android, iphone, flash, ios

I would like to port my 2D flash game to Android and iOS. Is there any cross platform engine you could recommend? [Corona](http://www.anscamobile.com/) is the only promising one I have found so far.

Comment: Just to add something useful. Here is a link about using Corona to port Flash apps. http://blog.anscamobile.com/2011/01/flash-to-corona-porting-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try http://gamesalad.com/. While Android publishing is not yet supported (planned for fall according to http://gamesalad.com/corporate/roadmap/) it can publish in HTML5, which should work well in many places, possibly android browsers too. YMMV.

Comment: I wish there was a version of game salad for PC :(

Comment: We are a mixed team: PC and MAC users. Unfortunately, a windows version of GameSalad [is not planned](http://gamesalad.com/wiki/faqs:gamesalad_support#when_will_gamesalad_creator_be_available_for_windows). Therefore, we decided to give the Corona SDK a try. Anyway, I will mark this as the right answer since GameSalad is in my opinion the only real alternative to the Corona SDK at the moment.

Comment: Not such a great option anymore as Android support is a premium feature.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use CS5.5 or Flash Builder 4.5 to take your existing game to mobile?

http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplatform/2011/06/build-mobile-apps-for-android-devices-blackberry-playbook-iphone-and-ipad-today.html

AIR 3.0, currently in beta, will also bring captive runtime (already available for iOS), where you can bundle the runtime with your app. The Flash Player 11 and AIR 3 betas are on Adobe Labs labs.adobe.com. If it doesn't work out for you, let us know why!

Emmy Huang, Group Product Manager, Adobe Gaming Solutions

Comment: Since the original game performs poorly, we are going to refactor large parts of the code. So there is no real benefit by sticking to AS3. In our particular case, we prefer native code over an AIR runtime environment.

Comment: @Matthias You want cross platform and native code?! How would that even work O_o

Answer (score 2):

Native code + cross platform solution.

Set up a Cmake build environment, cmake looks for installed compilers and builds make files for each platform... i.e.

You have a src folder with a cmake file, it tells cmake what's in it and how it links to other projects.

you have visual C++ 10 installed, cmake finds it via path variables, and uses it to build the visual studio 10 solution files from all of your source.

you rinse and repeat on each platform, windows is your win/android dev environment, a cheap mac mini to do your iphone/mac compiles, and a linux box if you so desire.

Android native requires cygwin and gcc.

From there you pick a well supported core library, I recommend STL or Boost which both have active port and optimization projects for them online.

You hide your core away via cmake so each build pulls the library optimized for your platform.

Additional libraries that are nice to have include a 2d rendering engine Skia or Cairo should do it, skia is more performant but has less documentation, don't let the Cairo openGL Backend fool you either, I hear there are issues with it.

You will need a sound library or something of the like, as well as a nice openGL library, since most of what I have done is mostly 2d graphics in the cross platform realm I can't help you on libraries for that.

Learning CMake for native cross platform is going to be hard work and you'll want to learn shell programming and windows batch or even better vbscript to automate some file creations and stuff when you want to add a new library to your application level code.

once you get your first file including skia/cairo with boost/stl and get a successful cross platform compile you will love yourself!!!!

I can tell you the build chains for everything though:

CMake

Windows Machine:
Visual Studio C++ 2010 (primary app development, do it here the debugging tools are amazing)
Android NDK
Android SDK
Cygwin (With GCC build tools and libs)

Mac Machine:
CMake
XCode
Iphone development Libraries

I would recommend source control as well:
Subversion or GIT = awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You can download AIR for android and iOS extension for Flash cs5 which enables you to port your flash apps to Android and iOS. I've tried porting into my android device and it works. For porting to iOS, you nedd a digital certificate from Apple, which will be provided to you only if you're registered as an Apple Developer. The two extensions are inbuilt in Flash CS 5.5.

You can get the android extension for Flash CS5 here http://hobbymerge.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/air-for-android-extension-for-flash-cs5-to-develop-apps-for-android-devices/