# What game engines can publish to Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios

I am about to start on a project which, at a minimum, will release to Android and iOS. Are there any game engines, other than Unity, which can publish to both? I fear that Unity might contain more overhead then we need, for what is essentially a 2D game.

Comment: Another one I've discovered on my own is Corona SDK which looks more focused for 2D but requires a subscription instead of a one time fee. After 2 years getting an ios and android liscense would be better price-wise and leaves the potential for additional build targets in the future.

Comment: MonoGame and ExEn.

Comment: UDK can also be used, but it can be difficult if your programming skills isn't that good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What 2D engine can I use to port my flash game to iOS and Android?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15703/what-2d-engine-can-i-use-to-port-my-flash-game-to-ios-and-android)

Comment: You're probably right about Unity being more than you need for a simple 2D game.  Using it would also limit the number of Android devices that could run your app.  Older, more basic, Android phones aren't Unity compatible.

Comment: There are so many. Have you tried googling?

Answer (score 5):

Those I know about are:

[Unity3D](http://Unity3D.com): A good 3D game engine, which is well known.
[Cocos2d-x](http://cocos2d-x.org): A C++ port of the Cocos2d engine for iPhone, which is a fully-featured 2D game engine.
[UDK](http://udk.com/): Another 3D game engine, which provides professional 3D tools at cost of being a little hard to learn.
[Corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/): I didn't test this one but I've read it's name in many threads (as well as comments here).
[Unigine](http://unigine.com/products/unigine/): This one is also a 3D game engine which lets you develop games using c++ language (and UnigineScript).
[Airplay SDK](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/): Another game engine (which seems to focus on 2D games) with support for almost all types of mobile devices.

Comment: Airplay would be perfect if it weren't for the yearly pricing structure as opposed to a one time fee like unity. Won't be using it for this but may use it in the future, thanks!